# Merge storyboards together in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I have a start.storyboard file that contains two basic view controllers. I also have my main.storyboard file that contains a tab bar view controller. While I see the benefit of using storyboard references, my question is if I can go the other way. Can I combine the start.storyboard and main.storyboard files, much like how I can go the other way with Refactor to Storyboard. I have included a screenshot of each storyboard below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, there is no really "good ways" to merge storyboard... The easiest way is to select your viewControllers, copy and paste in you main.storyboard.

Comment: Ok, got it. What about the swift files associated with the view controllers? Would I just update the class in the identity inspector?

Comment: Normally it will be done automatically. The segues are related with the viewController and not with the Storyboard.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Pierre Perrin: "The easiest way is to select your viewControllers, copy and paste in you main.storyboard." Regarding the swift files associated with the view controllers and whether or not you will need to update the class references in the identity inspector, "normally it will be done automatically. The segues are related with the viewController and not with the Storyboard."